# A question about 3 consecutive prime gaps

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Consider **any four consecutive primes**: p1, p2, p3, p4.  The **gaps** between these primes are even numbers g1, g2, g3  (We'll ignore the gap between 2 and 3).

**QUESTION: Are there any 'forbidden' sets of these 3 consecutive gaps values?**  For example, gaps (6,4,6) are very common, but (4,12,4) seem rare.

Comment: There's the basic "forbidden" set of $(2,2,2)$ since this means at least one $p_i$ is a multiple of $3$. This can only be if $p_1 = 3$, but then $p_4 = 9$ is not prime. You may wish to read the "Admissibility" section in [Prime $k$-tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple#Admissibility).

Comment: Thank you.  That’s a great resource.  This are is still quite new to me.